# Rails controller fails with TypeError - "Error during failsafe response"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Having an odd problem all of the sudden with my rails api application.

I get the following errors when a client calls one of my "get_auth_token" method.  The error seems triggered by attempting to load the base application_controler class (error occurs at line 1).

It's also a mystery to me why the app is running a select against "schema_migrations" at this point.

```
Started POST "/register/get_auth_token" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-31 11:56:17 -0800
(1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC

TypeError (wrong argument type Class (expected Module)):

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/registration_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
Error during failsafe response: wrong argument type Class (expected Module) 


/Users/jkramer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:181:in `include'
  /Users/jkramer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:181:in `block in add_template_helper'
  /Users/jkramer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:181:in `module_eval'
  /Users/jkramer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:181:in `add_template_helper'
  /Users/jkramer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:110:in `block in helper'
  /Users/jkramer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:109:in `each'
  /Users/jkramer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:109:in `helper'
  /Users/jkramer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_controller/railties/helpers.rb:17:in `inherited'
  /Users/jkramer/RubymineProjects/CrowdWisdomServer/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/jkramer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `load'
 ...
```

Here's the application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

And the actual controller being called:

```
class RegistrationController < ApplicationController
  def get_auth_token
    token = RegistrationManager.get_instance.get_auth_token(params)
    if token.nil?
      render json: {status: "authentication_failed"}
      return
    end
    render json: {status: :ok, auth_token: token}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was that the line

```
token=RegistrationManager.get_instance.get_auth_token(params)
```

which refers to a helper class called RegistrationManager that I had in the helpers subdirectory.  For reasons I still dont understand, if you refer to a class rather than module that lives in the helpers directory, Rails is unhappy.   Why it fails at line 1, I'm not really sure, but moving the class out of helpers into controllers/concerns solved the problem.   I wish the error messaging referred to the location of the bad call rather than at line 1, could have saved me and Mr. Adel a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

The moment i read your question i couldn't close the tab, I spent the last hour refreshing waiting for the answer, I tried to figure out what is the problem here and here is what i have reached, I noticed that your `ApplicationController` inherits from `ActionController:Base` which according to [Adding new Behaviour](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.3/classes/ActionController/API.html) in this link supports `ActionController::MimeResponds` by default which i think may cause a problem, So you think import from `ActionController::API` instead, I didn't try this in a real project but i'm guessing, About your wonder why does rails hit a query against your  migration table, I think you could find the answer [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8820), This is what i could figured out about your problem, Hope this helps.

Comment: Jeez.  Sorry bout that!  See the actual cause in the answer below.